# Location request timed out

Tags: react-native, geolocation

I want to fetch the current location of my device and I'm fetching it inside our office. But when I press the checkin button it always alerts with a message

```
findCoordinates = () => {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
        position => {
            // const location = JSON.stringify(position);
            console.log("LOCATION", position.coords.longitude, position.coords.latitude);
            this.setState({
                latitude: position.coords.latitude,
                longitude: position.coords.longitude,
            });
            this.props.onCheckin(this.state.latitude, this.state.longitude, this.props.employee_id);
        },
        error => Alert.alert(error.message),
        // { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 20000, maximumAge: 1000 }
        { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 5000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );

};
```

Comment: I just followed a code snippet to fetch the current location, that's why.

Comment: still the same problem "location request timed out". Actually I'm inside an office so is there any other way to achieve this??

Answer (score 2):

That's an issue with specific versions of android and can be solved by removing `enableHighAccuracy: true`